# Google Play Games Services "There is no linked app associated with this client ID"

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I know there are similar questions here already, but none of them contained a proper solution to this issue.

I have a libgdx project with enabled Google Play Games Services and matching SHA1 fingerprints. This problem happens after submitting the first score to a leaderboard, after this, the leaderboard can not be displayed anymore and the request returns this error:

```
14104-14148/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [568] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/played
06-14 12:12:50.358 14104-17900/com.google.android.gms W/GameAgent: Volley error when reporting played
   com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms:32)
       at lbf.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms:3)
       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms:11)
06-14 12:12:50.360 2953-12624/system_process E/AlarmManagerService: Unable to set alarm to 1497513600.000000000: Invalid argument
06-14 12:12:50.669 14104-14147/com.google.android.gms E/Volley: [567] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/scores?language=de_DE
06-14 12:12:50.675 2953-3084/system_process E/AlarmManagerService: Unable to set alarm to 1497513600.000000000: Invalid argument
06-14 12:12:50.812 14104-17901/com.google.android.gms E/MultiDataOperation: There is no linked app associated with this client ID.
    com.google.android.gms.games.server.error.GamesException
        at com.google.android.gms.games.server.GamesServer.getResponseBlocking(GamesServer.java:174)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.LeaderboardAgent.submitMultipleBlocking(LeaderboardAgent.java:969)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.LeaderboardAgent.submitBatchedBlocking(LeaderboardAgent.java:891)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.LeaderboardAgent.flushPendingScores(LeaderboardAgent.java:858)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.LeaderboardAgent.getRootPage(LeaderboardAgent.java:1068)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.DataBroker.getTopScoresPage(DataBroker.java:915)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.service.operations.leaderboards.LoadScoresOperation.fetchData$b7c4c52(LoadScoresOperation.java:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.service.operations.AbstractMultiDataHolderOperation.execute(AbstractMultiDataHolderOperation.java:53)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.service.operations.GamesOperationAdapter.execute(GamesOperationAdapter.java:23)
        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.BaseAsyncOperationService$OperationTask.run(BaseAsyncOperationService.java:177)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
06-14 12:12:50.825 2953-7238/system_process I/WindowManager: setFocusedApp token: Token{6e9cc60 ActivityRecord{6b16863 u0 de.limbusdev.snakebites.tv.lite/.AndroidLauncher t884}} requestedOrientation: 0
06-14 12:12:50.836 17350-17350/de.limbusdev.snakebites.tv.lite D/GameHelper: GameHelper: onActivityResult: req=5001, resp=RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED
06-14 12:12:50.836 17350-17350/de.limbusdev.snakebites.tv.lite D/GameHelper: GameHelper: onActivityResult: request code not meant for us. Ignoring.
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: PS: using Google Play App Signing - might that have to so something with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, you may need to update authorized URIs or JavaScript origins in Client IDs that you've created.

Also, note on this written warning in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#viewing_and_editing_project_settings_in_the_apis_console),

> Do not create new client IDs for your game from the Google API Console. If you do so, Google Play games services will not associate your game settings with the client ID, and this could cause errors during gameplay.

Here are the steps to modify attributes related to your OAuth 2.0 client ID (web origins and redirect urls for a web app, etc.):

> 1. Open the Google Play Developer Console and navigate to your game.
> 2. On the **Game Details** page, scroll to the bottom and click the link to the linked Google API Console project.
> 3. In the Google API Console, select your project.
> 4. In the sidebar on the left, select **APIs & auth**. Make sure that the Google Play Games Services API status is **ON** in the displayed list of APIs.
> 5. In the sidebar on the left, select **Registered apps**.
> 6. Expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section and find the attribute to
>      edit.